# How to set the hue order in Seaborn plots

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, bar-chart, hue

I have a Pandas dataset named `titanic` I am plotting a bar chart as described in the Seaborn official documentation, using the following code:

```
import seaborn as sns

titanic = sns.load_dataset("titanic")
sns.catplot(x="sex", y="survived", hue="class", kind="bar", data=titanic)
```

This produces the following plot:

[image: barplot by categories]

As you can see, the hue is represented by the `class`. How can I manually choose the hue order so that I can reverse the current one?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

In order to manually select the hue order of a Seaborn plot, you have to define the desired order as a list and then pass it to the plot function as the argument `hue_order` . The following code would work:

```
import seaborn as sns

titanic = sns.load_dataset("titanic")
hue_order = ['Third', 'Second', 'First']
sns.catplot(x="sex", y="survived", hue="class", data=titanic, hue_order=hue_order, kind="bar")
```

Answer (score 3):

`hue_order` is really useful if it has to be dynamically set. For example, the following code orders `hue` in ascending survival rate by class.

```py
df = sns.load_dataset('titanic')
# survival rate by class in ascending order
hue_order = df.groupby('class')['survived'].mean().sort_values().index
sns.catplot(x="sex", y="survived", hue="class", data=df, hue_order=hue_order, kind="bar");
```

---

As the [source code](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/master/seaborn/_oldcore.py#L1757-L1774) shows, if the data used for `hue` defines a `categories` attribute (e.g. pandas `category` dtype), the `hue_order` is set by these categories (however it is ordered); otherwise, it is set by the order that unique values appear in the data if it's non-numeric (such as `class` in the OP) or the sorted unique values if numeric.<sup>1</sup>

So another way to order `hue` is to change the order of the categories in the source dataframe.<sup>2</sup>

```py
# convert to a categorical variable with the categories in the "correct" order
df['class'] = pd.Categorical(df['class'], categories=['Third', 'Second', 'First'])
sns.catplot(x="sex", y="survived", hue="class", data=df, kind="bar");
```

[image: result]

---

<sup>1</sup> Using the `titanic` dataset built into seaborn, we can see these differences. The order is determined differently for each dtype.

```py
# category dtype
df['class'].dtype        # CategoricalDtype(categories=['First', 'Second', 'Third'], ordered=False)
g = sns.catplot(x='sex', y='survived', hue='class', data=df, kind='bar')
(df['class'].cat.categories == g.axes[0][0].get_legend_handles_labels()[1]).all()        # True
#           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  <---- categories determine the order

# for object dtype
df['embarked'].dtype     # dtype('O')
g = sns.catplot(x='sex', y='survived', hue='embarked', data=df, kind='bar')
(df['embarked'].dropna().unique() == g.axes[0][0].get_legend_handles_labels()[1]).all()  # True
#               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  <---- non-NaN unique values (in the order they first appear in the data) determine the order

# numeric dtype
df['pclass'].dtype       # dtype('int64')
g = sns.catplot(x='sex', y='survived', hue='pclass', data=df, kind='bar')
(np.sort(df['pclass'].dropna().unique()).astype(str) == g.axes[0][0].get_legend_handles_labels()[1]).all()  # True
#  ^^^^^              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  <---- sorted non-NaN unique values determine the order
```

<sup>2</sup> As a side note, you probably will want to convert all columns that contain categorical data into `category` dtype anyway. Among other desirable properties, it is much more memory efficient than the alternatives. For example, `sex` column consumes 6 times less space in memory if it's of dtype `category` instead of `object`.

```py
df['sex'].memory_usage()                     # 7256
df['sex'].astype('category').memory_usage()  # 1143

df['pclass'].memory_usage()                                                   # 7256
df['pclass'].astype(pd.CategoricalDtype(categories=[3, 2, 1])).memory_usage() # 1151
#                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ categories in a specific order
```